# Code blocks in user profile descriptions show up empty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

When viewing [this user's profile](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1186/lfzawacki), I saw the following:

[image: screenshot]

That empty area is a list of items, but it's indented four space so it looks like a code block.  Except it's showing up as empty instead of displaying the contents in monospace.

I believe this is related to Music's jTab plugin.  kiamlaluno did some good analysis of what's going on [over on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105628/code-blocks-in-user-profile-descriptions-show-up-empty/105630#105630).

Comment: I just edited the profile to use `<pre>` tags instead of indentation, the standard workaround. It might make sense to modify how jTab is configured so that it doesn't work on profiles, but it could also be conceivable that someone would *want* to use jTab in their profile…

Comment: In my opinion, the real problem here is that `<code>` is being used as the trigger for jTab, instead of `<div class="jtab">` (the jTab default) or something similar that won't conflict with any of the other formatting tags.

Comment: @Ben Exactly.  We should really have `<jtab>` or something instead, simple but unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact related to jTab available everywhere there is user entered text.  We stick to a standard convention of `<code>` due to the fact that a majority of our sites can then use the markdown button for { code sample } and enjoy specific parsing and rendering of the text entered by any 3rd party JS libraries.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info.